# pointers-inline meaning?

Tags: c++, pointers, inline

I have come across this while reading a program in C++

```
inline Controller* Get_it() { // ... bla bla
```

I don't understand what this means. Does this imply the definition of Get_it function? I have searched for files where Get_it function is defined, but didn't find it. I think that the syntax a* b means that b is pointer to point to objects of structure a, but there is no stucture Controller. There is though a class Controller defined somewhere else.

Thank you in advance people. I am new to C++ and I am trying to understand.

Comment: Yes that is the definition of the function. It returns a pointer to a Control class object

Answer (score 2):

The function `Get_it` returns a `Controller*`. That's a pointer to a `Controller`, which is a type that must be declared somewhere above this point in the translation unit. The function is marked `inline` which is a hint to the compiler that it can inline the code, basically copying the function body into every place it is called from.

These two things are separate. The pointer is not `inline`, the function is.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `inline` affects what it being defined, and is only
applicable to functions.  Formally, it allows (and in fact
requires) multiple definitions of the function.  It is also
a "hint" to the compiler that it should try to generate the code
for the function directly at the call site, rather than to
generate a call elsewhere.  (The motivation for the formal
definition is that the compiler typically cannot generate the
code inline unless it has access to the definition.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get yourself a good book on C++.  Secondly, that is a pointer to a `Controller` object (a class in memory).  It is returned by the function and the function is defined inline, meaning that it will be copied entirely to the callsite wherever it is called.

The `inline` word is a suggestion to the compiler to do inlining where sensible, but because you seem to indicate the function is defined inside the class declaration, it will be inlined by the compiler automagically.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword doesn't apply to the pointer (the return value of the function), but to the function itself. So here you declare (and define) an `inline` function which returns a pointer-to-`Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` keyword defines an method as inline<sup>1</sup>, no matter where it get's implemented. The signature above means, that the function `Get_it()` returns an pointer to an `Controller` object. The function itself is inline.

<sup>1</sup> Inline means, that the method get's not addressed through an vtbl, but get's directly allocated in the object's memory, so that there is no indirection when calling the method on an object instance, but the object instance itself grows in memory size.